# How do you make this perfect sphere of even quads and triangles?

Tags: modeling, procedural

How do you generate this? It is from: https://developer.blender.org/T57683

p.s. there's a triangle near the center of the image.

[image]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

1. In object mode `Shift+A` for Add -> Mesh -> Icosphere.
2. Popup opens in the lower left of screen, choose your subdivisions there.
3. In edit mode select all faces `Alt+J` for "tris to quads".

For bonus, here's all the sphere types at once (I got inspired and made this render):
[image]

Comment: 3 easy to follow steps - works perfect. Awesome. I find 5 subdiv levels seems to match op's image.